# Seaching for dam small hardware-pc-box /hardware vendors to embed for firewall product

Tags: firewall, hardware

We have developed squid based proxy content filter along with iptable-linux as router has nice webuser interface , we searching for type of small machine that suits to our product.

Here are the details:

**Software Dependency** :apache2 compiled ,sqlite ,PHP , squid-proxy ,squidguard,centos5.3 OS.
**Hardware Dependency** : two lan interface least 20 GB storage min-256 max 2GB RAM.

regards

chetanM

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with any of these companies but have bought 2 fine pieces from pcengines.ch - I can't speak for the quality of the others but I keep hearing mostly good stuff about them.

Have a look at:

- http://soekris.com
- http://pcengines.ch

The latter is a bit cheaper but not that strong on the hardware side. You might need to get in touch with them directly as standard options only hit your minimum RAM requirements.

Also have a look at EPIA VIAs segmented boards:

- http://www.via.com.tw/en/products/embedded/boards/index.jsp

I'm interpreting the Software Requirements as: "Must be able to run..." as you seem to have quite a customized setup already in place and just need the corresponding piece of hardware

Comment: Soekris sprung to my mind first - but I don't think it will meet the required specs.

Comment: Why, depending on the answer I migh save you investigating pcengines as I chose primarily between those 2

Comment: PCEngines are great ! VIA EPIAs tend to be very expensive for what they are. I think that Atom platforms will replace all of these :-)

Comment: we're running OpenBSD firewalls/routers on Soekris net 4801 and 4501 and apart of being maybe a little CPU underpowered for what you want they're very stable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this company [SmallPC](http://www.smallpc.com/)
Full power computers, very small packages.  Very well built as well, suitable for industrial use if needed.  Not all have the dual NICs but you can also do options for some of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot if not too much offerings if you search for "embedded PC". 
I'd say that you need a quite powerful CPU for content filtering.

My preferences for such appliances have always two points:
- fanless
- power supply integrated so that there are only power cord and network cords and no other clutter

If possible the console port should be network (but as most have serial, most racks have some kind of terminal server in place).

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend [PC Engines](http://www.pcengines.ch/), they pretty much offer the best value and performance in a small product. Or you could buy something like the [Intel BOXD945GCLF](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813121342) which includes an Intel Atom, just add ram, 2nd NIC, and a box.